# Contiguous memory in Forth arrays?

Tags: forth

I know that `variable test 5 cells allot` is not guaranteed to allocate a contiguous block of memory, while `create test 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 ,` will definitely create a contiguous block of memory.

`variable` is defined as `: variable create 0 , ;`

Is `allot`ing more cells to the variable not guaranteed to extend the block of memory contiguously because `create` can only be called once per word?

Example:

`create test 1 , 2 ,`
`test 3 , 4 , 5 ,` <<<< This won't necessarily extend the array contiguously, correct?

Are my assumptions correct?

Comment: Due to your use of the `gforth` tag, it's unclear whether your question is about Standard Forth or more specifically about Gforth.

Comment: @LarsBrinkhoff The question is about Standard Forth, I only used the `gforth` tag to show which Forth I was using. But I should have just written that I was using gforth, without using the tag.

Comment: The standard does carefully say that a VARIABLE can be anywhere, no guarantee that an ALLOT after it will allocate contiguous memory. Use CREATE, *and make sure nothing gets in the way before any ALLOTs*.  That gforth does it one way today doesn't mean a thing, they could very well rethink how it works tomorrow, even more so if it affects code the standard deems illegal or is at least fishy to start with.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- The wording in the standard gives `VARIABLE` and `CREATE` freedom to put the data in different memory regions.  If they do, obviously `CREATE` or `ALLOT` can't extend the region created by `VARIABLE`.
- `CREATE` can be called many times from any word.
- Your example may not quite do what you think.  The second line calls `test`, leaving its address on the stack.  Then it lays down three cells which do extend the region allocated for `test`.
- Your assumption about the definition of `VARIABLE` is not correct for all implementations.

Comment: If I added a `create`d word to the dictionary, next added another word (for example `test2`) and then tried to extend the first word with `n1 , n2 ,`, it may not be contiguous? If that is the case, would iterating the array with `1 cells +loop` make a semantic error?

Comment: No, that's not contiguous due to the addition of a new definition.

Comment: `,` is take number from stack, place it in current address of user data memory, then increase current address of user data by address size. This address is usually in `DP` variable. So, definition can be next: `: , DP @ ! DP @ CELL+ DP ! ;`